# What determines the quantum numbers which corresponds to an energy state for a particle in a 3D box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation

For a particle in a cubical box, The energy states are given by
$$E_{n_x,n_y,n_z} = \frac{\hbar \pi^2}{2mL^2}(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)$$

where $n_x,n_y,n_z$ are quantum numbers describing the state.

Below is an image which describes the combinations of quantum numbers describing a certain energy state.

[image]

I am confused as to why the 1st excited state is described by only having one of the $n_i = 2$, why is (2,0,0) not a valid combination to describe the 1st excited state $E_2$, and why does the 2nd excited state need two of the $n_i=2$ why is (3,1,1) or (2,2,2) not a valid combination to describe $E_3$.

I do not understand how we pick what the $n_i$ should be to describe a specific energy state.

Comment: yea, it's $\psi(x,y,z) = Asin(\frac{n_x \pi x}{L})sin(\frac{n_y \pi y}{L})sin(\frac{n_z \pi z}{L})$

Comment: I see there is no wave function for $n_i =0$, so that clarifies that. But I still do not understand why for $E_2$ why (2,2,1) or (2,2,2) does not describe the energy state but (2,1,1) does. Also I have edited the formula.

Comment: Yes but why does $2^2+1^2+1^2=6$ describe specifically $E_2$? why does $2^2+2^2+1^2=9$ describe specifically $ E_3 $?

Comment: So are you saying that each $n_i $ is iterated then $\sum{n_i^2}$ is computed, then the result is arranged in ascending order and each combination is then given an energy state in that order?

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you for your help. Sometimes what is super clear to you might not be clear at all to someone else.